# Add specific amount to each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                    A            B
 2015-05-20 19437808.95 32580962.68
```

I've got a dictionary(or DataFrame) that looks like this:

> {'A': 1000, 'B': 2000}

I want to reindex the DataFrame to the end of the month, like so:

```
                     A           B
2015-05-20 19437808.95 32580962.68
2015-05-21         nan         nan
2015-05-22         nan         nan
2015-05-23         nan         nan
2015-05-24         nan         nan
2015-05-25         nan         nan
2015-05-26         nan         nan
2015-05-27         nan         nan
2015-05-28         nan         nan
2015-05-29         nan         nan
2015-05-30         nan         nan
2015-05-31         nan         nan
```

Now I'm trying to figure out a way to add the 1000 to each row in 'A', cumulatively summing as we go along, so 2015-05-22 is actually +2000 from 2015-05-20.

I would need to add to each row by the corresponding amount in the dictionary of values. The output would look like this for the first couple rows:

```
                     A           B
2015-05-20 19437808.95 32580962.68
2015-05-21 19438808.95 32582962.68            
2015-05-22 19439808.95 32584962.68  
2015-05-23 19440808.95 32586962.68
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fill the `NaNs` with dictionary key-value pair and then take cumulative sum like - `df.fillna(value=key).cumsum()`

```
In [225]: key = {'A': 1000, 'B': 2000}

In [226]: df.fillna(value=key).cumsum()
Out[226]:
                      A            B
2015-05-20  19437808.95  32580962.68
2015-05-21  19438808.95  32582962.68
2015-05-22  19439808.95  32584962.68
2015-05-23  19440808.95  32586962.68
2015-05-24  19441808.95  32588962.68
2015-05-25  19442808.95  32590962.68
2015-05-26  19443808.95  32592962.68
2015-05-27  19444808.95  32594962.68
2015-05-28  19445808.95  32596962.68
2015-05-29  19446808.95  32598962.68
2015-05-30  19447808.95  32600962.68
2015-05-31  19448808.95  32602962.68
```

---

Where the initial `df` is

```
In [224]: df
Out[224]:
                      A            B
2015-05-20  19437808.95  32580962.68
2015-05-21          NaN          NaN
2015-05-22          NaN          NaN
2015-05-23          NaN          NaN
2015-05-24          NaN          NaN
2015-05-25          NaN          NaN
2015-05-26          NaN          NaN
2015-05-27          NaN          NaN
2015-05-28          NaN          NaN
2015-05-29          NaN          NaN
2015-05-30          NaN          NaN
2015-05-31          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know the value=key thing worked, that was what I needed. Thanks!